# Limit of a sequence!

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence of nonnegative numbers, and suppose that $\lim s_n = 0$. Prove that $\lim \sqrt{s_n}=0$.

I know if I let $|s_n| < \epsilon^2$, then this can be proved! But I want to know if the following reasoning is valid.

Proof.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, $\exists N$ s.t $|s_n - 0 | < \epsilon,\forall n > N$. This implies that $\exists N$ s.t $\sqrt{s_N} \leq \sqrt{s_n} \leq s_n < \epsilon$.

Comment: No, for $0 < x < 1$, you have $x < \sqrt{x}$. Use $\varepsilon^2$.

Comment: Oh, I did not account that case... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Proof:

Given any $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ for any $n \ge N$

$|s_n - 0| < \epsilon^2 \Rightarrow |\sqrt{s_n}| < \epsilon$.

Then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{s_n} = 0$.

In your proof, $\sqrt{s_N} \le \sqrt{s_n} \le s_n$ holds when $s_n$ is a monotonically increasing sequence in $[1,\infty]$.